# Adding and subtracting Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm doing a fairly basic statistics course (I'll apologise right away for how crap I am at it) and on an assignment I have there's a question where I'm not even sure what it's asking.

Let there be two independent Bernoulli random variables $X$ and $Y$, with probabilities of $p$ and $s$. Then we have $U = X + Y$ and $V = |X - Y|$.

My problem is that I have no idea what this means: is it saying $U$ is union of $X$ and $Y$? I'm sure that it can't be that $Pr(U) = p + s$. And as for $V$, I have even less idea.

I'll leave out the actual question for now, because this has so thoroughly confused me already (and I'm sure that once I know what it's saying, I'll have a solid chance of answering it).

Thanks in advance for answering this, and for putting up with my below average maths skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the range of Bernoulli random variables $X$ and $Y$ as $\{0,1\}$ with probabilities of success (denoted as 1) $p$ and $s$. Then the range of random variable $U$ is $\{0,1,2\}$. Hence $P(U=0)=(1-p)(1-s)$, $P(U=1)=p(1-s)+(1-p)s$, $P(U=2)=ps$. Similarly, you can compute the range of $V$ and its respective probabilities.

Comment: Okay. That makes a lot of sense.

So $V$ will be like that then too, but different because of the subtraction and absolute.

Am I right in saying that $P(V = 1) = p*(1 - s) + (1 - p)*s$

Comment: Yes you are right. Here the range of $V$ is simply $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Binomial distribution. As for the second question think about this : X-Y = X * (1 - Y)